# Reading null values from BufferedReader in command prompt input

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read from the user's input from command line. For the input for `filename`, the program is supposed to exit whenever it detects that the user has submitted a blank value.

However, the program is always going to the "Inside Reading file" code, regardless of whether the user input contains anything or not. It never gets to execute the "Program will exit now" code. I've tried different ways of coding it, and all of them came back with the same results. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String collection; 
    String filename;

    System.out.println("Enter the collection name: ");
    collection = br.readLine();

    String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/" + collection;
    solr = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);

    doc1 = new SolrInputDocument ();

    while (true){

        System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
        while ((filename = br.readLine()) !=null) {
            System.out.println("Inside reading file ");
            parseUsingStringTokenizer(filename);
            System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
        }
        System.out.println("Program will exit now...");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: An empty String is not the same as null. Try comparing the user's input to `""`

Comment: The program's behavior was the same regardless if I use null or "" in this original code.

Comment: That's because you're using == to compare Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add one extra condition `filename.trim().length()>0` with `(filename = br.readLine()) !=null`. As `!= null` will not check for whitespaces. And why you have put while(true). It is useless as per your current code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String collection; 
    String filename;

    System.out.println("Enter the collection name: ");
    collection = br.readLine();

    String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/" + collection;
    solr = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);

    doc1 = new SolrInputDocument ();

    System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    while ((filename = br.readLine()) !=null && filename.trim().length()>0){
        System.out.println("Inside reading file ");
        parseUsingStringTokenizer(filename);
        System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    }
    System.out.println("Program will exit now...");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this gets the correct behavior that I wanted. The while(true) was there originally to keep the program running as long as user enters something, but I agree that it is useless now after I restructured the code previously. Overlooked on that part. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedReader` returns `null` when the end of stream is reached. It returns `""` (the empty string of length 0) when the user enters a blank line.

Thus, you should change your loop condition to this:

```
while (!(filename = br.readLine()).equals(""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sometimes I get confused between null and "".